# Mongodb update operation inside sub array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am extremely new to mongodb and am facing a little trouble with an update operation. Here is the document:

```
{
    "username" : "amitverma",
    "notifications" : {
        "notification_add_friend" : [
            {
                "sender" : "macbook",
                "action" : "",
                "type" : "",
                "objectType" : "request",
                "objectUrl" : "",
                "isUnread" : true
            },
            {
                "sender" : "safari",
                "action" : "",
                "type" : "",
                "objectType" : "request",
                "objectUrl" : "",
                "isUnread" : true
            },
            {
                "sender" : "chrome",
                "action" : "",
                "type" : "",
                "objectType" : "request",
                "objectUrl" : "",
                "isUnread" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("526598c86f45240000000001")
}
{
    "username" : "macbook",
    "notifications" : {
        "notification_add_friend" : [
            {
                "sender" : "amitverma",
                "action" : "",
                "type" : "",
                "objectType" : "a_r",
                "objectUrl" : "",
                "isUnread" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("526598d06f45240000000002")
}
```

I want to remove the sub array with `{"sender":"safari"}` within `"username":"amitverma"`
I have tried $elemMatch with $set, but just couldn't get the query correctly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to delete the whole `notification_add_friend` array from the first document? *P.S. Actually there are two documents here*

Comment: I *think* the OP means to remove the "safari" request from the array but is wording it a bit strangely.  If the intention is to remove the whole array I'll delete/change my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `$set` here, but `$pull` ([see docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)), and while you *could* use `$elemMatch` to further specify your query, you do not need to.

The following would pull all add friend notifications with `{"sender": "safari"}` from the sub array of documents matching `{"username": "amitverma"}`

```
db.yourcollection.update({"username": "amitverma"}, { 
  $pull: {"notifications.notifications_add_friend": {"sender": "safari"}}
})
```

As to your comment, if you wanted to update a particular element you *would* use `$set` in combination with `$elemMatch` and the [positional operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).  For your example, something like:

```
db.yourcollection.update({
  "username": "amitverma", 
  "notifications.notifications_add_friend": {
    $elemMatch: {"sender": "safari"}
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    "notifications.notifications_add_friend.$.isUnread": false
  }
})
```

Comment: what if i want to change a particular property, say, `isUnread` to false.. how would I do that?

Comment: the update solution for changing the value of isUnread doesnt work.

Comment: It should work, are you getting an error or is it just not updating? And what version of mongo are you on?