# How to delete an object inside an array, inside an object inside an array with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's assume this is my data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52892936b996cc760d000002"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2013-11-17T20:38:14.248Z"),
"name" : "Two",
"subcategories" : [
    {
        "subcategory" : "Alpha",
        "products" : [
            {
                "name" : "Product 5",
                "primary_price" : "2",
                "secondary_price" : "3",
                "created_at" : "Sun Nov 17 2013 20:39:20 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Product 7",
                "primary_price" : "2",
                "secondary_price" : "3",
                "created_at" : "Sun Nov 17 2013 20:39:31 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "subcategory" : "Bravo",
        "products" : [
            {
                "name" : "Product 6",
                "primary_price" : "2",
                "secondary_price" : "3",
                "created_at" : "Sun Nov 17 2013 20:39:26 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Product 8",
                "primary_price" : "2",
                "secondary_price" : "3",
                "created_at" : "Sun Nov 17 2013 20:39:38 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Apple",
                "primary_price" : "5",
                "secondary_price" : "13",
                "created_at" : "Sat Nov 23 2013 12:00:18 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Lemon",
                "primary_price" : "9",
                "secondary_price" : "13",
                "created_at" : "Sat Nov 23 2013 12:00:32 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

And I'd like to delete "Product 5" How can I do it with mongo (hopefully without having to loop and/or do any data transformation?

I've tried the method described here: [how to delete a specific object from array object in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394246/how-to-delete-a-specific-object-from-array-object-in-mongodb)

here [Deleting a single object from an array of objects in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423873/deleting-a-single-object-from-an-array-of-objects-in-mongodb)

and here [Mongodb update operation inside sub array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505045/mongodb-update-operation-inside-sub-array)

I'm assuming the reason it didn't work is because my object is double nested. I've been trying to find a solution the ones I come up involves data manipulation which I'd rather avoid.

Help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you link to is basically the same question.  I'm not sure what you tried, but this would work (in the shell):

```
db.test.update(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52892936b996cc760d000002"), 
        'subcategories.subcategory': 'Alpha'
    }, 
    {$pull: {'subcategories.$.products': {name: 'Product 5'}}})
```

The query object identifies the `subcategory` element to target for the `$pull` on `products` via the `$` operator.

Comment: But if understood this correctly, this will delete every instance of "Product 5" that is inside a subcategory "Alpha". That's not what I'm after. I want to delete only the "Product 5" that's inside subcategory "Alpha" that is inside object id "ObjectId("52892936b996cc760d000002"". How can I achieve that? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK OK; then you just need to add that as another query term.  See updated answer.